# pullback of a morphism of locale which is an isomorphism?

Tags: locales

Let $A,B$ be two locales over a locale $X$, and $f:A\rightarrow B$ a morphism of locale over $X$. Let also $g:X'\rightarrow X$ be a surjection of locale such that the pullback of $f$ along $g$ is an isomorphism between $A\times_X X'$ and $B\times_X X'$. The general question is: Does $f$ is an isomorphism ?

Of course this is not true in general. It will be the case for example if $g$ is an open surjection.

My precise question is : Does it work when we only assume that the two maps from $A$ and $B$ to $X$ are open maps ? (In this situation, I can proove that $f$ is a monomorphism and that is image is fiberwise dense over $X$, but I have not been able to do more or to construct counterexample)

Thank you !

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to define what you mean by a locale over a locale and for some of the other notation or at least give a reference.

Comment: A locale $A$ over a locale $X$ is simply a locale $A$ endowed with a morphism from $A$ to $X$ (as in any type of geometry I think). In this special case, one can also see this as a locale $A$ internal to the category $Sh(X)$. For the others notion (surjection, open surjection, pullback and fiber product of locale), any basic references on locale would work (the Handbook of categorical algebra Vol. 3 of borceux, the part C of the Elephant of Johnstone, "Sheaves geometry and logic" of MacLane and Moerdjik, Frame and locales of Picado and Pultr, and maybe others that i do not know.

Comment: I forgot an important precision: I consider the category of locales as the opposite of the category of frames. (apparently there exist some references which use the opposite convention)